# Show parent.name instead of parent.id in RABL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rabl

I have a RABL file:

```
collection :@points
attributes :id, :point_type, :name, :coordinates
child :point_pages do
  attributes :point_page_type
  child :point_page_classes do
    attributes :auto_class_id, :show_price   # I need to change this line
  end
end
```

So, `point_page_class belongs_to :point_page` and `belongs_to :auto_class`.

I need to show in `attributes` of `point_page_class` not the `id` of `auto_class`, but the `name` of it. But, of course, in `point_page_classes` table in DB I have only `auto_class_id`.

I need something like:

```
child :point_page_classes do
  attributes AutoClass.find(auto_class_id).name, :show_price
end
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glue` method did it:

```
collection :@points
attributes :id, :point_type, :name, :coordinates
child :point_pages do
  attributes :point_page_type
  child :point_page_classes do
    attributes :show_price
    glue(:auto_class) do
      attributes :name
    end
  end
end
```